# Existing authentication with ServiceStack ServerEventsClient

Tags: c#, authentication, events, servicestack, push

I'm looking for a way to use an existing session ID with the ServiceStack ServerEventsClient. I'd like to use server events, but access will need to be limited to authenticated users.

For JsonServiceClient, I have a method in a library referenced by all of our projects which returns an authenticated JsonServiceClient ready to be used. The purpose is to make development a bit faster by keeping all auth info in one place:

```
public static JsonServiceClient GetAuthenticatedServiceClient()
{
    var ServiceClient = new JsonServiceClient(globals.ApiUrl)
    {
        RequestFilter = request => request.UserAgent = globals.ClientSoftware.ToString()
    };

    var CookieQuery = (from c in globals.AuthCookieContainer
                       where c.Name == "ss-id"
                       where c.Expires > DateTime.Now
                       select c);
    if (CookieQuery.Count() > 0)
    {
        ServiceClient.CookieContainer.Add(CookieQuery.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exceptions.ApiNotAuthenticatedException();
    }

    return ServiceClient;
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to implement something similar to the above method for ServerEventsClient? I'm trying to avoid sending an Authenticate request, since I've already got an easy way to get to session information on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L114) used to maintain the CookieContainer for each ServerEvents request is just a `JsonServiceClient` so you can access its concrete type with just:

```
var client = (JsonServiceClient)serverEventsClient.ServiceClient;
```

So you can take the same approach of transferring cookies between any service client.

The [ServerEventsClient.Authenticate](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L626) literally just makes an `Authenticate` request on the same ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient instance so it gets populated with the returned cookies from a successful response.